# Enable Rainbow Brackets for Dart in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

I am using Android Studio for Flutter development. 
I have Dart plugin installed and now I added Rainbow Brackets plugin that should be very useful working with Dart.

[image]

Unfortunately this works in Java and is not working for files in Dart.
What can be done with it? How can you enable rainbow brackets for dart in Android Studio.

p.s. 
using Visual Studio Code is not an option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found solution - new Android Studio 3.1 version and updating Rainbow Brackets plugin

Answer (score 0):

It works in my env even without a dart sdk installed. Please comment your env as below, so that I could targeting issues:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-181.4203.519, built on March 22, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b20 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.3
```

See [more info](https://github.com/izhangzhihao/intellij-rainbow-brackets/issues/13), if you want to have a talk, [gitter](https://gitter.im/izhangzhihao/intellij-rainbow-brackets) would be a good choice.